# Trouble with align* environment

Tags: align, amsmath

I have no idea what the following code is giving me an error; I

```
Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
```

Could you please enlighten me as to where the mistake is? Thank you very much.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
$$\begin{align*}
    d(a, b) &\le d_0(a, b)\\
    \iff \dfrac{y}{1+y} &\le y\\
    \iff y &\le y+y^2\\
    \iff 0 &\le y^2
\end{align*}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Erroneous nesting of equation structures` did tell you that you had something `extra`.

Comment: Independently of not having to be used with an amsmath environment, it should not be used with LaTeX.  When you have a numberless displayed equation, use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: @CasperYC I'll try to remember that.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah I have to read that thread with the benefits of \ [ \ ] over $$ $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        d(a, b)             & \le d_0(a, b)\\
        \iff \dfrac{y}{1+y} & \le y\\
        \iff y              & \le y+y^2\\
        \iff 0              & \le y^2
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You don't really need the `$$` for this environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! Ahhh I hate all these little rules that are never explicitly said anywhere.

Comment: I got used to it now. I was like the same. Had to try different `variations`.

Comment: @Ovi These are not obscur weird rules ;) As explained in the mathtools package documentation, there are two versions of environments for mathematics: inner and outer. align is an outer environment, so it is not meant to be nested. The inner version is aligned, which can be used inside equation, for instance. One obvious reason for such a structure is that outer environments can number your equations, be labeled, and so on.
I hope that this short explanation will help you.